# JSON to CSV conversion on HDFS

Tags: json, csv, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to convert a JSON file into CSV.

I have a JAVA code which is able to do it perfectly on UNIX file system and on local file system.
I have written below main class to perform this conversion on HDFS.

```
public class ClassMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        String uri = args[1];
        String uri1 = args[2];
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
        FSDataInputStream in = null;
        FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(new Path(uri1));
        try{

            in = fs.open(new Path(uri));

            JsonToCSV toCSV = new JsonToCSV(uri);
            toCSV.json2Sheet().write2csv(uri1);
            IOUtils.copyBytes(in, out, 4096, false);

            }
        finally{
            IOUtils.closeStream(in);
            IOUtils.closeStream(out);
        }
    }

}
```

json2sheet and write2csv are methods which perform the conversion and write operation.

I am running this jar using below command:

```
hadoop jar json-csv-hdfs.jar com.nishant.ClassMain /nishant/large.json /nishant/output
```

The problem is, it does not write anything at /nishant/output. It creates a 0 sized /nishant/output file.

Maybe the usage of `copyBytes` is not a good idea here.

How to achieve this on HDFS if it is working OK on unix FS and local FS.

Here I am trying to convert JSON file to CSV and not trying to map JSON objects to their values

Comment: No it is not similar issue. Here I am trying to convert JSON file to CSV. In the link mentioned by you, it is trying to map JSON objects to their values.

Comment: Why don't you SQL utilities for this case like Spark SQL, Hive?

Answer (score 0):

FileSystem needs only one configuration key to successfully connect to HDFS.

```
conf.set(key, "hdfs://host:port");  // where key="fs.default.name"|"fs.defaultFS"
```